# Cannot resolve the dependencies in gradle build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Recently I have updated the Android Studio and also the SDK.
While rebuilding my app project i m getting following error...

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
  >   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.jar
  >        file:/C:/android new SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.pom
  >        file:/C:/android new SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.jar
  >        file:/C:/android new SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.pom
  >        file:/C:/android new SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        AppOne:app:unspecified
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.913 secs
...............................................................

My Gradle file config is as follows ..

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Do you have install the latest support repository from internal SDK manager of Android Studio?? It is necessary to update the repository and install the compatibility pack before calling compile guideline

Answer (score 0):

Take android sdk manager and update

- Android support Library
- Android support Repository

It will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install/Update the Android support Library and Android support Repository first and then rebuild the project.